# How can I filter div as per selected value from dropdown optionlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs the first time it will show all but when I change the value from dropdown options then all div should be hidden and just one div should appear as per selected value.

It's working for one option like as I did for `panel-1` but now I want to it should be work for all options list how can I do it?

```js
$('#medicalHistoryFilter').on('change', function() {
  var selectedFitler = $(this).find(':selected').val();

  if (selectedFitler == 'panel-1') {
    $('#accordion').find('.panel').hide();
    $('#accordion').find('#panel-1').parents('.panel').show();
  } else {
    $('#accordion').find('.panel').show();
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select class="form-control" id="medicalHistoryFilter">
    <option>Filter</option>
    <option value="panel-1">panel-1</option>
    <option value="panel-2">panel-2</option>
    <option value="panel-3">panel-3</option>
    <option value="panel-4">panel-4</option>
    <option value="panel-5">panel-5</option>
  </select>

  <div class="clearfix"></div><br>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div id="panel-1">This is panel 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div id="panel-2">This is panel 2</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div id="panel-3">This is panel 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div id="panel-4">This is panel 4</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div id="panel-5">This is panel 5</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Option list may be multi there is no limit so we can't do it with if else condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the correct panel with `$('#'+selectedFitler)`.

*PS: I also edited your code a bit:*

*To get your `<select>` value, just use `$(this).val()`.

No need to use a `.find()` method, you can just select all your panels with `$('#accordion .panel')`.*

```js
$('#medicalHistoryFilter').on('change', function() {
  let selectedFitler = $(this).val();
  if (selectedFitler.startsWith('panel-')) {
    $('#accordion .panel').hide();
    $('#' + selectedFitler).parent().show();
  } else {
    $('#accordion .panel').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="medicalHistoryFilter">
  <option>Filter</option>
  <option value="panel-1">panel-1</option>
  <option value="panel-2">panel-2</option>
  <option value="panel-3">panel-3</option>
  <option value="panel-4">panel-4</option>
  <option value="panel-5">panel-5</option>
</select>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="panel-1">This is panel 1</div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="panel-2">This is panel 2</div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="panel-3">This is panel 3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="panel-4">This is panel 4</div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="panel-5">This is panel 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Literally seconds away from posting the exact same code, but I fixed the typo :p

Comment: Thanks its working fine but there is little bit issue when i select first option `<option>Filter</option>` that is by default when i select this option all divs should be open.

Comment: Thank you! @Zenoo